How can a class be used to define function args in Python?
I'm wondering if it's possible to use a class to define function args in pure Python, or maybe by using a package.
For example:
class FunArgs:
    first: int
    second: str

def my_fun(FunArgs):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_fun(first=1, second="OK")

The reason to use that syntax is just its simplicity.
Often we tend to add too much of args in functions and also put notes about them, which reduce its readability.
The example is very simple, but in general those types are longer and more complex, which reduce readability more.

I actually don't hate the structure of my_fun(FunArgs(first=1, second="OK")). I think Selenium does something similar under certain circumstances?

@ThierryLathuille  My curiosity is if it's possible or not rather than right or wrong. But thank you!

@AndrewYim "Selenium does something similar under certain circumstances?" Would you share the reference to it?

You can pass options to a browser using a browser options class - https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/

This is OK as long as you are programming in some make-believe world.  In the real world, the function my_fun will have two arguments if and only if the logic of the function requires them.  If you put those arguments into a class for the sole purpose of making the function signature look nice, the code inside the function will have to pull those variables out of the class object in order to use them.  Writing extra code to create the class, and writing code of extra complexity in order to access the variables, is not a good use of your time.  I think you ought to forget this idea.

I won't go too much into details about the appropriateness of such an approach to class design (after all, Python's philosophy is basically "do whatever you want as long as you know what you are doing").
The simplest way you can get to such a syntax is using dataclass.
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class FunArgs:
    first: int
    second: int

def my_fun(fun_args: FunArgs):
    print(f'This is first: {fun_args.first}')
    print(f'This is second: {fun_args.second}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_fun(FunArgs(1, "OK"))


Thank! That'd a good alternative as @AndrewYim already said

Yup. It's just that @AndrewYim didn't mention about the dataclass so I thought I'd just put a fleshed out example here.

Good! This use case is really helpful, indeed. The example is Pydantic

This isn't a recommendation, but if you're looking to increase the readability in your codebase, consider using a decorator that validates **kwargs based on a provided dataclass. This way, you can avoid passing a dataclass instance when calling your function. Instead, the dataclass serves solely for validating that the correct arguments are passed, similar to how a Python function with named arguments would behave if an argument is missing. You define the decorator once (in this case args_with_class) and then you can reuse it on all your functions. You are free to change the name to something that makes sense for you.
This validation in the decorator is just an example, Pydantic might be a good option here.
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields
from typing import Callable, Type

@dataclass
class FunArgs:
    first: int
    second: str

def args_with_class(dataclass_type: Type):
    def decorator(func: Callable):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # Extract dataclass fields
            required_fields = {f.name for f in fields(dataclass_type)}
            
            # Check if all required fields are present in kwargs
            missing_fields = required_fields - kwargs.keys()
            if missing_fields:
                raise TypeError(f"Missing required arguments: {', '.join(missing_fields)}")

            # Call the actual function
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper
    return decorator



@args_with_class(FunArgs)
def my_fun(**kwargs):
    print(f'This is first: {kwargs["first"]}')
    print(f'This is second: {kwargs["second"]}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Correct usage
    my_fun(first=1, second=2)

    # Example with incorrect types
    try:
        my_fun(first=1, second="OK")
    except TypeError as e:
        print(e)

    # Example with missing arguments
    try:
        my_fun(first=1)
    except TypeError as e:
        print(e)


I believe Pydantic was created for this very purpose.

@Hanstjua can you still pass arguments in this way my_fun(first=1, second=2) with Pydantic? If so how? The example uses a dataclass, but there is nothing that stops you from using Pydantic in the decorator for validation.

Sorry I was referring to the validation part. Thought I'd mention pydantic since in your code you tried to implement the validation from scratch.

Yes that's just not to use any dependency. I updated the answer. Thanks
